# how to use multiple parameters when combining expressions using Expression.Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression

Ok so here's the problem I am creating an expression dynamically to execute against the database, that works fine. the problem appears when I add another expression using Expression.AndAlso, the expressions combine fine but the parameters don't work, my code is below.

```
Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> condition = null;

ParameterExpression[] param = new ParameterExpression[sessionModel.FilterChildren.Count];

foreach (var filter in sessionModel.FilterChildren) {

   param[i] = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Invoice), filter.SysName);

   Type type = Type.GetType(filter.Type);

   if (i == 0)
     condition =
         Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(
             Expression.Equal(
             Expression.Property(param[i], filter.SysName),
             Expression.Constant(filter.Value, type)
            ),
              param[i]);
    else {
      var newCond = Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(
         Expression.Equal(
             Expression.Property(param[i], filter.SysName),
             Expression.Constant(filter.Value, type)
            ),
              param[i]);

       var test = Expression.AndAlso(condition.Body, newCond.Body);

       condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(test, param);
    }
    i++;
  }
```

it throws an error

```
Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
```

there are different parameters for each expression that will be added.

any ideas where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you assign a value to `condition` before `if` block?

Comment: I've updated my question to show what is called just before :)

Comment: Well, I'd expect a NullReferenceException as you do `Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> condition = null;` and then if if block is not triggered `var test = Expression.AndAlso(condition.Body, newCond.Body);` but I guess `i` is initially 0 as well, so that's not the case. Which line throws the exception? `AndAlso` part seems to be Ok to my inexperienced eyes tbh.

Comment: Shortly - you should use one and the same parameter.

Comment: the issue is on the line condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(test, param); the and also seems to work fine

Comment: Care to elaborate @IvanStoev just so i can understand further

Comment: @IvanStoev You mean instead of `param[i]` he can only use `param` which should not change with every foreach iteration?

Comment: @uteist That's exactly what I meant:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to use multiple parameters when combining expressions using Expression.Lambda

You shouldn't be using multiple parameters. The lambda expression

```
Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> condition
```

implies single parameter of type `Invoice`.

To fix the issue, replace

```
ParameterExpression[] param = new ParameterExpression[sessionModel.FilterChildren.Count];
```

with

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Invoice), "invoice");
```

and in the rest of the code, replace `param[i]` with `param`.

P.S. There is no real need to create lambda expressions for each filter because as you can see, when combining them you use only the `Body`. The whole procedure can be trimmed down to something like this:

```
Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> condition = null;
if (sessionModel.FilterChildren.Any())
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Invoice), "invoice");
    var body = sessionModel.FilterChildren
        .Select(filter => Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, filter.SysName),
            Expression.Constant(filter.Value, Type.GetType(filter.Type))))
        .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
    condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: Just trying to learn, so it might sound stupid, but what's the reason behind this? Isn't `param[i]` also a `ParameterExpression` as expected in `Expression.Lambda` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But they are **different** objects and not considered to be one and the same. Even the names doesn't matter. So the real trick is to use one and the same parameter expression **instance**.

Comment: makes sense :) Thanks for that...Legend

Comment: Just added a simplified way of doing the same (for learning purposes :)